# Silverlight: Where to store data used across pages

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that consists of many pages that uses Navigation Framework. What is the ideal place to store data that should be accessed across all pages (XAMLs) and throughout 
the lifetime of the application.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I am currently doing it as a static class

Comment: You can use static members on a helper class

Comment: @Wakeed That's what I am doing now. Thought there would be a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static members are generally a bad idea. You have no control over lifespan or ability to easily substitute another set of data (and don't get me started on the inability to do proper unit testing). You want to use some type of shared View Model/Data model.

If you are not going the whole PRISM route (we always use PRISM now for Silverlight and WPF), or Unity, or even just MVVM, then use simple singleton accessors on your data object.

There are lots of discussions over the best patterns for C# singletons, but you can learn a lot here http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the difference between singleton and static class if I want the data persistent throughout the application lifetime

Comment: @andromeda: A singleton class is far more adaptable to change compared to individual static properties. You can more easily make it not static for testing and you can control when it is created (with static variable they are only created before the app start).

Answer (score 0):

I like to create a class called `Session`, with a static property like this `public static Session Default {get {return App.Current.Resources["Session"] as Session;}}`, then create a new instance of it in `app.xaml` like this `<classes:Session x:Name="Session"/>`, now you can access it in code behind with `Session.Default...` and you can bind to it with `Source` binding and it will always be the same instance. I have expanded this pattern to a more complex and flexible pattern with base classes etc but that should suffice for your purposes. I wrote this code in this web window, it might not compile, if you need more help just let me know